# How to interpret negative values for -2LL, AIC, and BIC?

Tags: interpretation, spss, aic, bic

From a statistical point of view, can -2LL, AIC, and BIC in the table of information criteria from SPSS output be less than zero, ie negative? In this case, how should they be interpreted?
Note: These negative values were obtained while examining a two-level growth curve model to investigate volume growth trajectories over three time occasions using the SPSS software program. The histogram of the dependent variable (volume) after a two-step normalization procedure was as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The bottom line is that (as Jeremy Miles says) the value of the negative log-likelihood doesn't really matter, only differences between the negative log-likelihoods. But you might still wonder *why* you are getting negative values.

Reproducing an answer of mine from [here](http://emdbolker.wikidot.com/faq):

Technically, a probability cannot be >1, so a log-likelihood cannot be >0, so a negative log-likelihood cannot be negative. AIC/BIC etc. are composed of negative log-likelihoods plus positive 'penalty' terms (except in cluster analysis, where people typically flip the sign of the definitions!), so they can't be negative either.

**However**, there is one common case where we can get negative values for the "negative log-likelihood" function we use (which in these cases *isn't exactly a negative log-likelihood*). (These in turn can give rise to negative AICs (i.e., $-2\log(L)+2k<0$).)

For continuous response variables, what we are writing down is really a negative log-likelihood **density function**, rather than a negative log-likelihood function. For example, here's a picture of the normal density with μ=0,σ=0.1.

[image: Normal distribution peaking around 4]

You can see that the density goes above 1, which means that the log density is >0, which means that the negative log-likelihood *density* is negative. This will happen any time the likelihood curve is very narrow.  (Mathematically, there should be an infinitesimal $dx$ term in our expressions — we typically ignore this because it doesn't affect our inferences.)

---

Another common scenario (but not one where I have found an example) is that we often drop the *normalization constants* in likelihood expressions because they're a nuisance and they don't affect inference. *If* we had a discrete distribution (so that the likelihood was really a probability and had to be <= 1) *and* the normalization constant was sufficiently small, dropping the normalization constant could in principle give us an expression that was >1. I haven't found an example where this actually happens, though ...

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

-2 LL means -2 multiplied by the log likelihood.

AIC, BIC etc are (as far as I know) only interpreted in relation to other values from different models. An AIC of -100 doesn't mean anything on its own. It means something when a different model, using the same data, has an AIC of -90, so the difference is 10. The difference is the interesting thing.

Comment: AIC can be interpreted as twice the negative expected log-likelihood of a new data point from the same data generating process. I have written about that [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/497988/aic-calculation-with-very-low-negative-log-likelihood/497992#497992) and elsewhere, and others have too; see e.g. some of [these threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=twice+the+negative+expected+log-likelihood).